# Popup div/iframe disables other controls?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying to show and hide (toggle) iframe window on button press. The iframe should cover some of my controls, but I need them still working.

For some reason even if not covered at all, some controls just get disabled. Am I doing something wrong with the css?

This is my code:

```js
function ToggleIframe(){

  $( ".iframeHolder" ).toggleClass( "iframeHolderShow" );

}
```

```css
.iframeHolder {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:99999;
}

.iframeHolderShow {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin-left:100px;
  left:10px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:99999;
}

.backgroundDiv{
  margin-left:100px;
  
  width: 420px;
  height: 400px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-size:1px;
  color:#3498db;
  background-color:#ffffe6;
  z-index: 1;
}

button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border:none;
}

button:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

    <button id="btnShowHideIframe" onclick="ToggleIframe()">
        Show/Hide
    </button>

<div class="iframeHolder">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KxtgS2lU94" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="backgroundDiv" class="backgroundDiv"> 
    <button id="btn2ShowHideIframe" onclick="ToggleIframe();">
        Show/Hide 2
    </button>
</div>
```

You can see how the second button (Show/Hide2) gets inactive when the iframe appears into the blue div.

To see it more clear, here's a link on codepen too:

http://codepen.io/ZlatinaNyagolova/pen/VjQKJo

I will continue working on it there (jfy in case there is inaccuracy in the code).

Comment: @charlietfl - it's the same even if i remove completely the z-index property :\

Comment: Be much simpler if you wrap button and iframe in same container. `<div><toolbar/><iframe></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `padding-top` property in the CSS. I use it to position my iframe, but it hovers some controls underneath. So in alternative, I used just `top` - that does not affect my other controls and the iframe is still properly positioned.